# Antd calendar change month on day cell click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, frameworks, antd

If you work with Calendar component from 'antd', then you mentioned that when you click the day of previous/next month, it will change the month automatically.

How to prevent this behaviour?
https://ant.design/components/calendar/#header

Answer (score 0):

**1. Disable dates**

You can disable dates that not in current month. This should prevent clicking on them.

```
<Calendar value={selectedDate} disabledDate={disabledDate} />
```

```js
disabledDate = currentDate => {
  return currentDate.isSame(this.selectedDate, 'month'))
};
```

**2. Prevent selecting**

In case you want more control. You can set value manually with `onSelect` checking if current selected date is in current month.

```
<Calendar value={selectedDate} onSelect={this.onSelect} />
```

```js
onSelect = date => {
  if (date.isSame(this.selectedDate, 'month')) {
    this.setState({
      selectedDate: date,
    });
  }
};
```

**Note**

- In this examples [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/query/is-same) is used and supposed you followed
  [How to use Calendar with customize date library like dayjs](https://ant.design/docs/react/replace-moment#Calendar)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the mode in onSelect and it gives you control only over the date and does not change the month in the dropdown.

```
 const onSelect = (value, mode) => {
 if (mode.source == "date") {
  // do something
  }
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).